# Throw an exception from a thread WITHOUT using Callable?

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, concurrency, runnable

So I am in a scenario where I have a method that returns absolutely nothing. (Return type Void). I need to run it another Thread though. I know you can throw an exception using callable, but unfortunately the exception won't be thrown until the Future.get() is called and since it returns nothing, calling the future.get() just seems like a waste. Is there any more elegant solution to my problem? Here is mockup of the issue I am running into:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Callable<Void> upStreamer = new Callable<Void>(){
        public Void call() throws IOException{
            throw new IOException("I want this exception to be thrown!");
        }
    };
    FutureTask<Void> futureTask = new FutureTask<Void>(upStreamer);
    Thread uploadThread = new Thread(futureTask);
    uploadThread.start();   
}
```

Here is the real issue in pseudocode:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
new somekindOfThreadLikeThing...
     //inside the method
     if(criticalCondition == false){
        throw new IOException("halt everything and tell the programmer what's wrong.");
     }
     //Import code that is the part that needs to be multithreaded but the final references will screw it up. (There are inmutable Strings involved. Code will throw uncaught exception if criticalCondition == false. This part will also throw an exception.
}.startOrWhatever();
}
```

Comment: Is the above code what you have now or what you'd like to move towards?

Comment: It's what I tried to do with Callable. Due to the nature of my code's composition, it's not easy to simply call future.get().

Comment: Ok the title suggest you don't want to use Callable.  Do you?

Comment: Nope. I'll write some pseudo code to illustrate my problem.

Comment: I don't get, why you don't want to use a Callable. It is ecactly made for this pupose. Can you explain, why you think it is less ellegant?

Comment: You're going to have to synchronize with the other thread to get the exception anyway. Any other solution will be more or less the same.

Comment: Also, on the point of calling get() being a waste, what else would you want to happen? get() provides a synchronization point for your main thread to say "ok, now I'm ready to see how that background operation went". You either get a value back, or you immediately get an ExecutionException to let you know it failed - there's no waste. The only other possible conceptual scenario would be for the background thread to interrupt the main thread in the middle of whatever it was doing, and that would certainly be less elegant. Or, more concisely, what @SotiriosDelimanolis just said :)

Comment: Then what does Thread.start() do in the case? Isn't future.get() now I am ready to see what you returned WHEN the Thread is done? I need the rest of the program to continue on with it's duties. Wouldn't future.get() cause the main thread to wait until the Callable's call() method is completed? If it doesn't then I will happily use that setup. It's just my (possibly flawed) understanding that the call() function must be complete when .get() is called.

Comment: Does your program need to know if the background thread succeeds? If you want to check for progress periodically you can call isDone() - this will return true if the thread has finished, whether normally or due to an exception. And isDone() won't block.

Comment: That might work, but how would I know if it was due to an Exception or not. Basically, in the above method I am sending data in the URL and in the other I am waiting for a response. I don't want the thread to be waiting for a response that will never come. So I need to know if it failed not if succeeded.

Comment: You would use an observer pattern to be notified when the thread is done. Then call get.

Comment: Once `isDone()` returns true, you can call `get()` and know it won't block - if it throws an Exception, catch it

Comment: What about CompletableFuture?      http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to use CompletableFuture. Thanks so so much ssedano!

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html